# How is the bandgap reference diode so accurate? (temperature changes bandgap?)

Tags: temperature, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I am studying about bandgap references ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandgap_voltage_reference)). As a black box approach, (from what I know) it can be seen as a system which gives a stable voltage reference irrespective of the highly varying operating conditions. The voltge is said to be fixed due to the nature of the bandgap of the silicon being constant. It is said to be temperature independent, defeating many of the problems of reliability that they had at the time this was released in circuits.

However, I came across this article which shows how the bandgap of the pn junction silicon (and other doped semiconductors) changes with respect to temperature. ([source](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/eband.gif))

[image]

So, does it work on the principle that the change in the bandgap over the temperature of interest is small?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, as the schematic in your referenced wikipedia page shows, the stability is because it's the **difference** between two P-N junctions.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate what you mean? Is it that even though the bandgap changes with temperature, the difference in two different bandgaps is the same? (at the same temperature)

Comment: I think the name is a slight misnomer. The bandgap circuit is simply a combination of absolute temperature measurement and analog computation to offset the temperature dependence of a junction. It does this to first order. Slightly more complicated circuits that do this to higher order are used on modern chips. The much more precise way to produce precision sources is to actually stabilize the physical temperature of the junction itself, rather than to compensate for its temperature dependence electronically. Extremely precise temperature compensated voltage references do just that.